# Adding Tags to log Groups created by DMS task

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-dms

I created Database migration tasks using terraform but it looks like the logs groups get created automatically. I am hoping to add tags to the logs as we have an SCP that checks for tags on resources created. Is there a way I can do this or DMS just creates this automatically?

Ability to create tags on log groups created by DMS

Comment: I see that there is a way to set enable logging here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.Logging.html  using this json file but I am not sure how to add tags to it

Comment: I'm not familiar with DMS log groups, but if this is similar to AWS Lambda's auto-generated log groups, what you have to do is figure out what the log group names will be ahead of time, and create those log groups explicitly in Terraform, and add a `depends_on` clause to your DMS resources so that they won't be created until after Terraform has created the log groups. If you don't want to delete the resources that have already been created, then you could `terraform import` the existing log groups so that Terraform could start managing the tags on them.

Comment: Thanks MarkB. I will try that and provide feedback!

Comment: I tested this out and it worked. I only ensured the log groups were created with the same name AWS would have created them with while also ensuring they get created before the replication tasks. Thanks alot for your help MarkB!